# "Inherit" move operations without access to base-class member variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, move-semantics

Being new to rvalue references and move semantics, I'm trying to derive a simple template class from `std::vector` (I promise I'll be careful with the lack of virtual destructor). To "inherit" the move constructors, I simply call the base class counterparts and `std::move`,

```
template <typename T>
class Vec: public std::vector<T> {
  public:
    ...
    //move ctors
    Vec(Vec&& v): std::vector<T>(v) { //move extra members with std::move }
    explicit Vec(std::vector<T>&& v): std::vector<T>(v) { //same as above }
    ...
};
```

which seems trustworthy based on my understanding of C++. However, I have a lot less confidence in my approach for the move assignment operators,

```
    //assignment
    Vec& operator=(const Vec& v) {
        std::vector<T>::operator=(v);
        if (&v != this)
          //copy extra members
        return *this;
    }
    //move assignment
    Vec& operator=(Vec&& v) {
        std::vector<T>::operator=(v);
        //move extra members with std::move
        return *this;
    }
```

Is this a foolproof way of achieving what I want? Are there better alternatives in terms of good practices?

Comment: A good guideline is [the rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Although I still prefer writing `=default` and `=delete` everywhere.

Comment: @Barry, yes me too, but I consider that to still follow the rule, just being more explicit about the fact you are consciously not defining the members yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which seems trustworthy ...

It *seems* trustworthy. But it isn't. You see, this:

```
Vec(Vec&& v)
```

is a move constructor. So it would get called with an rvalue. But once we're inside here, `v` is an lvalue! Rule of thumb: if it has a name, it's an lvalue. So this part:

```
: std::vector<T>(v)
```

doesn't call the *move* constructor of `std::vector`. It calls the *copy* constructor. You need to explicitly cast `v` to an rvalue to do the right thing:

```
Vec(Vec&& v) : std::vector<T>(std::move(v)) { }
explicit Vec(std::vector<T>&& v): std::vector<T>(std::move(v)) { }
```

Or, better yet:

```
Vec(Vec&& ) = default;
```

Similarly, the foolproof way of writing the assignment operators is just `default`-ing them:

```
Vec& operator=(Vec const& ) = default;
Vec& operator=(Vec&& ) = default;
```

But if you really have special logic, make sure you remember to cast to rvalue there too:

```
Vec& operator=(Vec&& v) {
    std::vector<T>::operator=(std::move(v));
    // stuff
    return *this;
}
```

Or even better, move your special logic into a self-contained unit so that `default`-ing is still right.

Comment: @downhillFromHere `default` explicitly does the default version of whatever the function is. If you have member variables, a `default` assignment operator will be a member-wise assignment. If you need to do resource management, you should encapsulate that so you can take advantage of Rule of Zero.